# Gigabyte GA-P55-UD6: booting weirdness after BIOS update

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I had to flash the latest BIOS into a Gigabyte GA-P55-UD6, because the system didn’t recognize some more modern devices on USB. All settings are more or less standard (no overclocking, etc.). Only SATA drives are mounted, no RAID. After this I checked and updated CMOS settings and set boot order. Nevertheless when booting the system hangs with ‘Loading Operating System ...’ unless I go into boot manager (F12) and select the correct hard drive.

Obviously I've missed something, but what?

Comment: Are you saying the boot order configuration is not being saved?

Comment: No, the boot order configuration was saved, but I've mixed up some drives with similar names. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and remove it from your question.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED! I've mixed up the names of some drives when re-configuring the boot sequence. Sorry for bothering!